# How to get HBase IP address for Phoenix URL

Tags: hadoop, hbase, apache-phoenix

I can ssh to the Hadoop Cluster and can run the `hbase` command. But I need to connect using the Phoenix JDBC driver which needs the IP address of the HBase server.

I tried the IP address I used for the cluster with no luck.

This is probably just a generic Hadoop question but where are the IP addresses configured?

Comment: Is it a custom distribution like HDP or Cloudera that you use or is it just a standalone installation  of Phoenix over HBASE that you have ?

Comment: In my case it is "CDH 5.7.3".

Answer (score 0):

If you are aware of the hadoop cluster namenodes, then you can try pinging them or send a curl request like below

```
curl 'http://my-namenode-lv-101:50070/jmx?qry=Hadoop:service=NameNode,name=NameNodeStatus'
{
  "beans" : [ {
    "name" : "Hadoop:service=NameNode,name=NameNodeStatus",
    "modelerType" : "org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode",
    "SecurityEnabled" : false,
    "NNRole" : "NameNode",
    "HostAndPort" : "my-namenode-lv-101:8020",
    "LastHATransitionTime" : 1561605051455,
    "State" : "standby"
  } ]
}
```

If the state is Standby, then that is the current inactive node, you have to try the other nodes to find for which the State says 'active' ... example below:

```
curl 'http://my-namenode-lv-102:50070/jmx?qry=Hadoop:service=NameNode,name=NameNodeStatus'
{
  "beans" : [ {
    "name" : "Hadoop:service=NameNode,name=NameNodeStatus",
    "modelerType" : "org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode",
    "State" : "active",
    "SecurityEnabled" : false,
    "NNRole" : "NameNode",
    "HostAndPort" : "my-namenode-lv-102:8020",
    "LastHATransitionTime" : 1561605054944
  } ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To connect to phoenix-hbase  use the **zookeeper address**, **port** & **zookeeper.znode.parent configuration's value** which is configured in your cluster. (it can be found in your hbase-site.xml file)